# Remove string between two characters

Tags: objective-c, ios

This my example string

> String of words in (brackets) to be (removed)

I want to remove all the words inside brackets, along with the pair of brackets, after which the string will look like this:

> String of words in to be

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use reg expression to remove the string
Like following ( this `@"\\(.+?\\)"` is the regexp for string between ( and ) )

```
NSMutableString *str = [@"String of words in (brackets) to be (removed)" mutableCopy];

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\(.+?\\)"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:NULL];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:str 
                      options:0 
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])  
                 withTemplate:@""];
```

Comment: Be careful with your wording, it is a regex for a single line string starting with '(' and ending with ')'.  Between implies only the content without the parenthesis.

Comment: @Omar If i want to remove only last bracket in the sentence then how should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can split string on space bases then after you take array index..and combined that string.